# Adding items on ArrayList

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

In my application, i am  having scan button. On its click i am opening another application "BarcodeScanner" which scans the barcode and returns the result to my application in onActivityResult where i am adding the result on ArrayList. 
           If i again click scan button and again open BarcodeReader application to scan the next barcode, my previous result on the arraylist is getting cleared. So everytime i get the result of BarcodeScanner, only recent result is present on ArrayList. How to maintain all reslutls so that i can show all scanned barcodes in a list? Please help..

Here is my code

```
     public void onClick(View v){
        //check for scan button
        if(v.getId()==R.id.scan_barcode){


            //instantiate ZXing integration class
            IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
            //start scanning
            scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        //retrieve result of scanning - instantiate ZXing object
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        //check we have a valid result
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            //get content from Intent Result
            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            //get format name of data scanned
            String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();

            //Add to arraylist
            barcodes.add(scanContent);




                 }                
        }
        else{
            //invalid scan data or scan canceled
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: show your code. You need to add the barcode results in arraylist using for loop.

Comment: make your array list static

Answer (score 0):

1)you can use sharedprefereces to store data in arraylist

2)you can not finish your arralist activity when start barcodescanneractivity

**arralist will be declare global..and u must add the value in arraylist...**

i hope its useful trick to you.

Comment: Yes it can be done by SharedPreferences.. But is there any other alternative?

Comment: I have already declared the arraylist globally..Still it is not working

Comment: 2)you can not finish your arralist activity when start barcodescanneractivity

Comment: or other option is to declare static arralist in your activity.

Comment: Yes. I have just declared the arrayList as a static. And it worked..Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Store the array list in **shared preferences**.

**Note**: Also provide a button, on which click, you can clear that list stored in shared preferences if you want. Many times, especially for *testing* purposes, you may want to refresh that list. So by providing an option for that, you can reset the arraylist, or *still* maintain data between different app executions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me your code?
If the arraylist is a varaible on class level, it shouldn't be like that.

Here is the sample to help:

```
BarcodeScanner scanner = new BarcodeScanner();
ArrayList<Result> list = new ArrayList<Result>();

public void onActivityResult() {
   Result value = scanner.receiveScan();
   list.add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 . In your `MainActivity` pass the Globally declared **ArrayList** through the `intent` to the SecondActivity using `startActivityForResult()`

```
//Pass the ArrayList from the MainActivity
intent.putExtra("ARRAYLIST", arrayList);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE);

// In your on Activity Result get the data
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if(extras != null){
    arrayList = (ArrayList) extras.get("RESULT_ARRAYLIST");
}
```

---

2 . Get the `ArrayList` in the `SecondActivity`, you can perform the operations on the Arraylist in the SecondActivity, When you are finished just pass the same ArrayList using the Intent by using `setResult(resultCode, data)`

```
// Get the Data in the SecondActivity
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null){
    resultArrayList = (ArrayList) extras.get("ARRAYLIST");
}

// When you are finished
intent.putExtra("RESULT_ARRAYLIST", resultArrayList);
setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
```

Comment: I have just made the ArrayList as a static.. and its working fine :)